# Excel formula is parsed but not evaluated

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function

As can be seen from the screenshot I have entered what seems to be a valid formula (also see this: ) . However excel just prints the formula *and not the result* in that cell.

```
 =SUM(+C50:C51)
```

[image]
What should be done differently here?

**Update** I have tried numerous  varieties of formulas here, and have been simplifying them repeatedly just to eliminate sources of problems. I do not believe the formula is wrong - and the cells were already updated to `number` type. So not clear what is going on.

Also tried (but with no change):

```
 =Sum(c5:c51)
```

(without the leading `+`)

Comment: Is the cell incorrectly formatted as text?

Comment: it looks like it is - yes . How can the cell be cleared of that formatting so it can display the formula result?  btw please make this an answer

Comment: Select the cell and right click and pick format, the change back to General.

Comment: I had tried that after your first comment  but it still only prints the formula. I'll mess around a bit more

Comment: Clear contents, then change format, then put the formula back.

Comment: The formula had a small corruption and after fixed this worked. Feel free to make as an answer

Comment: @javadba, your data range has `TEXT` format that's why values are left aligned otherwise Excel would have convert them in `Scientific notations` , `1.23146E+14`.

Comment: Also, the question states a formula but the image shows a different formula.  The reason for your problem will be different depending on which one you're using.  Can you clean up the question?

Comment: You fixed the typo in the formula, but it still doesn't match what's in the image.  Those are two very different formulas.

Comment: I'm  tired from trying so many different varieties . The formula and screenshot are in sync now. I'm about done with this question.

Comment: It looks like some kind of corruption.  That formula should work (without the +).  Try the formula in a different cell.

Comment: @fixer1234  I had already tried that as well - re-entering the formula in other cells.

Comment: Try it in a new spreadsheet.  Start with just the formula.  Then copy and paste the data cells above it.  If that works, it could be that the original spreadsheet is corrupted.  If that's the case, you may have success by selecting all of the cells in the workbook and copy/paste into a new workbook.  Sometimes the workbook "infrastructure" gets hosed.  A fresh spreadsheet solves that and then the cell contents will work if you plug them in.

Comment: Done that.  I simply can not spend more time on this. I would delete the question if I could.

Comment: If you don't see a delete link under the question, it's probably because it has received an answer.  You can flag a moderator and ask them to delete it.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because OP comments: " I simply can not spend more time on this. I would delete the question if I could."  If the OP chooses not to interact on this question anymore, it is unanswerable because the OP's work to this point shows that more diagnostics would be required.

Answer (score 0):

**N. B.**,

*Below shown **Solution 1** is related to OP's previous version of the problem which has been updated by the OP owner Yesterday with the CURRENT ISSUE.*

**Solution 1 (For Previous issue):**

**Basically your Formula `=sum(len(c2:C52c51))/49` has typo & as well as syntax error.**

You have used Range `C2:C52c51`, remember Excel never allows use of Range in such a manner. It should be `C2:C52`. May be you are confused with Syntax of `SUM` function which should carry multiple ranges separated by comma like, `=Sum(C2:C52,C53)` or `=Sum(C2:C52,D2:D52)`.

Since you are trying to Sum the Length of the Range in that case you need an CSE (Array) formula and your formula should be written like this.

```
{=sum(len(C2:C52))/49}
```

**Note,** finish the formula with `Ctrl+Shift+Enter`.

**Or**, *to avoid the Array formula you can use this one.*

```
=SUMPRODUCT(LEN(C2:C52))/49
```

**Edited:**

**Solution 2 (For current issue):**

The syntax of the formula is wrong, it should be written like shown below.

=`sum(+C50,C51)` or the best one is `=sum(C50,C51)`

*Remember purpose of putting + sign is to add the cell value with rest values and in fact while adding few cells it doesn't required.*

This should be an useful Syntax to SUM: `=SUM(+E164,H165:H180)`.

Where Excel adds `E164's` value with SUM of `H165:H180`.

Another one `=SUM(H164:H174,-E164)`.

Comment: The typo got introduced when I was messing around - and was not the original source of the problem.  The data type was the issue.   I have updated the screenshot to indicate the same.

Comment: This Solution is purely around your previously posted problem where you have show this formula `=sum(len(c2:C52c51))/49` and data type was never the issue with it !! I've has suggested correct version of formula which are working. Now what you have posted is a different issue !!

Comment: @javadba, Since your values are left aligned mean are `TEXT` type data but remember in general Excel keeps 11 digits as `NUMBER` and if are more than 11 then converts it into `SCIENTIFIC NOTATION` after that if you convert them in `TEXT` even that  they appear as  `SCIENTIFIC NOTATION` . If your VALUE starts with ' (apostrophe symbol) `'123145933421704` then only value will look like `123145933421704` as you have shown in screen shot and in that case if you apply the above shown formula get  `#Value` error.

Comment: *Contine,,,,,*         @javadba, Actually your formula should written like this `=sum(+C50,C51)` or I can say the useful should `=sum(+C50, C51:C100)`. Remember purpose of putting `+` sign is to add the cell value with rest values. Another I can show you, `=SUM(H164,-H165,H166)` will **Add** `H164` with `H166` and **Subtract** `H165` from that.

Comment: *Contine,,,,* or check thsi one `=SUM(I164:I167,IFERROR(-H177,0),H164,H165,H166)` this will **ADD I164 to 167**, then **Subtract** `H177` from the SUM and again **ADD** `H164,H165,H166` with the value.

Comment: @RajeshS, there's a long comment thread on the question with the last few posts hidden unless you expand it.  The last version of the OP's formula should work but it doesn't.  Looks like something is corrupted.  The OP tossed in the towel on this one and doesn't want to deal with it anymore.  They wanted to just delete it but can't, probably because of this answer.  If the OP chooses not to interact on this question, it's unanswerable.  Valiant effort, though.

Comment: @fixer1234, you are correct just Yday OP has replaced the issue with current one. So that just now I've edited my post with proper explanation & with solution of current issue. Plz review the post & suggest should I keep or delete it. Since for  the benefit of the community  I've stretched the answer. ☺

Comment: The OP tried it with and without the +.  It should work but Excel won't accept it as a formula.  The only thing I can see that would cause that is corruption.  The OP already tried some fixes, but none worked.  You've put a lot of work in on this one, but most of it applies to errors that the OP already edited out.  The OP's preference is to delete the question, so nobody will see this anyway.  If you delete the answer, it will facilitate putting the question out of its misery.  :-)

Comment: @fixer1234, this I've written in comments above for the issue Y =Sum(C5:C51) is not working,, **If your VALUE starts with ' (apostrophe symbol) '123145933421704 then only value will look like 123145933421704 as you have shown in screen shot and in that case if you apply the above shown formula get 0 or if you use =SUM(+C5:C51) get  #Value error**.

Comment: Right, but they don't get an error, either, because Excel never accepts the formula.  The formula just sits there as inputted text, like in the image.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/81203/discussion-between-rajesh-s-and-fixer1234).